# Multiple Group parameter in aggregate functions

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Is this possible? how else can I achieve what I want if it's not?

My report has 3 groups, I want to display the count of records in my details section and it should consider the groups. I created a count formula like `Count({FieldToCount},{GroupField1})`, this works fine but it only considers 1 group while I have 3.

Comment: can you update your question with layoutof your report. Willgive a better picture.

Comment: place same formula in all groups as `Count({FieldToCount},{GroupField2})` and `Count({FieldToCount},{GroupField3})`